# Conversion of an array of integers to string

Tags: python

In order to save memory space. Strings inside an embedded device are stored in a particular way. Each 32-bit location holds up to 4 chars instead of only 1 char in the usual case.

I wrote a function that convert an encoded string back to its original string. I am new to Python, so I would like to know whether or not I can simplify my code.

The string is encoded in such way that I need to reverse the order of each group of 4 chars.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
def arrayOfInt2string(array):
    s = ''
    for a in array:
        a = "%0.8x" % a
        b = list()
        for i in range(0, len(a), 2):
            b.append(chr(int(a[i:i+2], 16)))            
        s = s + ''.join(b.reverse())
    return s

r = (
    0x33323130,
    0x37363534,
    0x00000038,
    0x00000000
)
arrayOfInt2string(r)
```

The output is:

```
"012345678"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are going to be playing with string representations of native types, you probably want to take a look at the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) standard library package.

With it, you can quickly process your `r` as follows:

```
>>> import struct
>>> ''.join(struct.pack('i', rr) for rr in r)
'012345678\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

And you can play with the ordering of the characters by explicitly describing the endianess of your input:

```
>>> ''.join(struct.pack('>i', rr) for rr in r)  # big endian
'32107654\x00\x00\x008\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Answer (score 4):

First, your function name could use a more clear name. `arrayOfInt2string` contains a lot of information but none of it makes it clear what the user of function actually *is*. `decode_str` is more clear. Likewise, `array` is a bad parameter. The data you're passing is a tuple, not an array. But regardless the type is not a good indicator of what it is. `encoded_str` would be clearer. As much as possible, come up with relevant names to make your script easier to read.

You can initialise `b` just using `b = []`. But even better would be to use a list comprehension. A list comprehension collapses a for loop into a single line expression to generate a list. In your case, you can create your whole `b` list in just one line like this:

```
        b = [chr(int(a[i:i+2], 16)) for i in range(0, len(a), 2)]
```

It basically flips the syntax of your `for` loop around. You have your expression for each element of `b` followed by the syntax of your `for` loop. If you really wanted to, both `for` loops could be collapsed this way, but that would probably read as too complicated to follow.

For your `s` assignment, you can use the `+=` operator. It basically says to add whatever is on the right of the operator to the current value of `s`. It's shorthand to essentially do what your code already does.

```
        s += ''.join(b.reverse())
```

Using `''.join(b.reverse())` is not strictly necessary. You can use the slicing operator to reverse it in a shorter line. You've used the slicing operator elsewhere, but you may or may not be aware of the third parameter it takes called the *step* parameter. It basically tells Python what amount to increment each step by, similar to the third parameter you pass to `range`. You can pass a negative value to start at the end and go backwards, so you can flip `b` like this: `b[::-1]`.